# Flutter & Textfield : How do I restrict my user from using space in textfield by automatically removing that space?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, onchange, textformfield

How do I restrict my user from using space in textfield by automatically removing that space when the user finish typing?

For example, if the user type `King of Light`, it will apply as `KingofLight` after he/she steps away from the textfield.

```
TextFormField(
                          initialValue: nickname != null
                              ? nickname
                              : current_user.nickname,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Empty',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey[400],
                              fontSize: 20,
                              //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                          validator: (val) => val.length < 2
                              ? 'Enter a nickname 2+char long'
                              : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            val = val.replaceAll(' ', '');
                            setState(() => nickname = val);
                          },
                        ),
```

please help me! thank you!

Comment: see `TextInputFormatter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you do this is like this using `TextEditingController` and can call `formatNickname()` as per your use case.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>{
  
  FocusNode node = new FocusNode();
  TextEditingController tc = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    node.addListener((){
      if(!node.hasFocus){
        formatNickname();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  
  void formatNickname(){
    tc.text = tc.text.replaceAll(" ", "");
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          focusNode: node,
          controller: tc,
        ),
        TextFormField(),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Format'),
          onPressed: (){
            formatNickname();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Text field which does not allow spaces, using RegExp. As below-

```
            TextFormField(
               inputFormatters: [
                if (denySpaces)
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                      RegExp(r'\s')),
              ])
```

Above solution worked for me, to block space from keyboard.

Comment: Seems a robust solution against the combination of `FocusNode` and `TextEditingController`

Comment: What is the variable denySpaces?

Answer (score 3):

Another option to disable the possibility of writing spaces in a `TextField`, you can use an input formatter to restrict the allowed characters.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class NoSpaceFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // Check if the new value contains any spaces
    if (newValue.text.contains(' ')) {
      // If it does, return the old value
      return oldValue;
    }
    // Otherwise, return the new value
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

We created a new class called `NoSpaceFormatter` that extends `TextInputFormatter`. The `formatEditUpdate()` method is called whenever the user types or deletes a character in the `TextField`.

Inside the `formatEditUpdate()` method, we check if the new value contains any spaces by calling the `contains()` method on the text property of the `newValue` parameter. If it does contain spaces, we return the `oldValue`, which prevents the user from typing the space character. Otherwise, we return the `newValue`, which allows the user to type the character.

To use the `NoSpaceFormatter` class in a `TextField`, you can set the `inputFormatters` property to a list containing an instance of the formatter:

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [NoSpaceFormatter()],
  // Other properties...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    TextFormField(
       style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                     RegExp(r'\s')),
        ],
   )
```