# Implementing Mention in a Social Media App in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, social-media, mention

While implementing a normal mention where a user has a unique "`@Userhandle`" is quite easy, I've been struggling with implementing one where the mention text is a "`@User Name`", with spaces and everything, and the main issue, **names are not unique.**

*Example:*

"`I'm glad to announce @John Doe and @John Doe are appointed as the secretary of flutter committee."`

Here when we need to replace the names with there corresponding IDs before calling the API. And knowing which *"John Doe"* is which is not possible from the text.

The format in which I want to send the text to Backend is:

`"I'm glad to announce @{John Doe:aef123-af12-ef123} and @{John Doe:f123as-dff12-f1f3} are appointed as the secretary of flutter committee."`

Tried using a Map to store the selected mentions and then appending them to the name of the text using the following code. But this will append same IDs to the final text.

```
  String getTextIdMapped() {
    return text.splitMapJoin(regex, onMatch: (Match m) {
      if (m[0] != null) {
        final String? key = valueInUserNameMap(m[0]);
        if (key != null) {
          return m[0]!.replaceAll("@${userNameMap[key]}", "@${userNameMap[key]}=<$key>");
        } else {
          return m[0]!;
        }
      }
      return "";
    });
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

I will try to come back with an answer with code but in the mean time consider not allowing spaces in usernames - many website, applications or anything that needs a specific id removes the ability to add spaces to such imported id of your data store (for instance usernames).

Here is what im trying to pass on to you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64239679/flutter-textfield-how-do-i-restrict-my-user-from-using-space-in-textfield-by#:~:text=Another%20option%20to%20disable%20the,to%20restrict%20the%20allowed%20characters.&text=We%20created%20a%20new%20class%20called%20NoSpaceFormatter%20that%20extends%20TextInputFormatter%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64239679/flutter-textfield-how-do-i-restrict-my-user-from-using-space-in-textfield-by#:%7E:text=Another%20option%20to%20disable%20the,to%20restrict%20the%20allowed%20characters.&text=We%20created%20a%20new%20class%20called%20NoSpaceFormatter%20that%20extends%20TextInputFormatter%20).

Comment: Most don't, but we are trying to remove the concept of userhandles from our social media platform. Also LinkedIn has the functionality we are trying to implement.